# UploadCare doesn't load image in dialog

Tags: javascript, uploadcare

I expect the UploadCare dialog to open after clicking MyButton, showing the Twitter logo, but it doesn't. Why not?

```
$('#MyButton').on('click', function() {
    uploadcare.openDialog('https://g.twimg.com/About_logoUsage.png');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a `file` object as an argument to `openDialog` method. You can obtain the file object by calling [uploadcare.fileFrom](https://uploadcare.com/documentation/javascript_api/#file) method:

```js
// Pre-load an image from arbitrary URL,
// and open Uploadcare file upload dialog
$('#MyButton').on('click', function() {
    var file = uploadcare.fileFrom('url', 'https://g.twimg.com/About_logoUsage.png');
    uploadcare.openDialog(file);
    return false;
});
```